# htaccess redirect using a plus sign

Tags: .htaccess, bit.ly

bit.ly has it such that if you do

bit.ly/blah+ it redirects to bit.ly/info/blah

How would the htaccess code look for replicating that (using a plus sign to redirect to a related page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) code to do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\+$ /info/$1 [L,R]
```